# How does recursion exactly work?

Tags: python-3.x

I know that recursion has something to do with calling a function inside of a function, but I don't know how to code it. Since it's "calling a function inside of itself", I tried this:

```
#recursion function
def recursion_function():
    print("this is a function")
    recursion_function()
```

And there was no output in the console. How do I fix this? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to call the function initially, then it'll loop.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by calling the function "initially"; can you please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As S. Dev previously answered, you need to call the function.
The code you posted was only the function implementation.

Also as it is right now, your recursive function will run indefinitely because you don't have any kind of exit condition, so probably you'll want to do something similar to this instead.

```
#recursion function
def recursion_function(n):
    if(n > 0):
      print("this is a function")
      recursion_function(n-1)

recursion_function(5)
```

Now this way, you have an exit condition and you won't be getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function once in order to trigger the loop.

```
def recursion_function():
    print("this is a function")
    recursion_function()

recursion_function()
```

Python will eventually trigger an `RecursionError` though, if its an open-ended loop.

Comment: how can I make this a close-ended loop, then?

Comment: Something within `recursion_function` needs to break the loop with either the `break` keyword, or by returning before the next execution of the loop.